# How to get inserted mongo id after a POST request using baucis

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, baucis

I'm using express + baucis + mongoose to make a basic CRUD API for my models stored in mongodb.

```
var app = express();

mongoose.model('workgroup', WorkGroupSchema);

baucis.rest('workgroup');

app.use('/api', baucis());

var server = app.listen(4100);
```

So far this is working fine, I can make any request to create, update and delete my workgroups.

Now, I will need to do some more actions (update the workgroup permissions) when a user creates a workgroup, and for this I will need to get the mongo id of the recently created workgroup.

I tried adding another express middleware after baucis, handling only post for workgroups:

```
app.post('/api/workgroups', workgroupPermissionUpdater.update.bind(workgroupPermissionUpdater));
```

When workgroupPermissionUpdater.update is called I was hoping to find the mongo id of the created workgroup in the res param (every middleware receives req, res and next as params), but its not there.

Anyone knows how I can get the id of the created workgroup?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I researched a bit into this and tried a few hacks with the baucis middleware as it stands today, but was not able to get a satisfactory solution with it (happy to hear otherwise from the community).

I ended up deciding to cut baucis out of the picture and deliver this functionality through [mongoose middleware](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) instead.

```
//WorkGroup.js file
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
// other settings here

var WorkGroupSchema = new Schema({
  name: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('WorkGroupSchema', WorkGroupSchema);

WorkGroupSchema.post('save', function (doc){
     console.log("Do something with the WorkGroup " + doc.name + "just created " + doc.id);
});
```

You will have access to all the other properties of the instance of the newly created instance of the module. You can as well [hook](https://gist.github.com/aheckmann/2889412) to events such as 'new', 'update',...

Answer (score 1):

Using mongoose middleware as @Andrea_C mentioned looks like the best solution here.

You could also use an outgoing stream which is better in some situations:

```
controller.request('post', function (request, response, next) {
  request.baucis.outgoing(function (context, callback) {
    // do something with context.doc.id
    callback(null, context);
  });
  next();
});
```